# JavaScript: В цикле заполнить объект данными

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в javascript(без jQuery) в цикле forEach заполнить объект элементами и этот полученный объект поместить в массив:

```
newArr = [];
newObj = {};
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv a')).forEach(function(e) {

    data = e.getAttribute('data'); //строка, например "Фрукты"
    value = e.innerHTML;  //строка - "Апельсин"
    //тут надо вставить в объект полученные данные data и value

});
```

В итоге нужно получить объект внутри массива такой конструкции:

```
newArr= [
           {Фрукты: "Апельсин"},
           {Овощи: "Томат"};
        ]
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого подойдет [метод `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), и [вычисляемые имена свойств добавленные в ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

```
newArr = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv a'), function(el){
    return { [el.getAttribute('data')] : el.innerHTML };
});
```